# Zend framework --- Action code before rendering view

Tags: zend-framework, view, controller, rendering, action

When I use zend framework, how to run action code in controller before rendering view?

Now I use 2 action functions,

The first one have no view. The second one have the expected view.

When the first function is called, at the end of the function it will be redirected to call the second function.

Although I find this method works, the user cannot go back to last page by browser back button.

Comment: show some code, to many possibilities to guess.

Answer (score 0):

i don't understand your question so much but ...
Controller is always run before render action. Its a logic which running before render is called. I dont know from your question what you really need =( try be more objective pls. If you need run any code before action in controller on all actions in controller, you use **init** or **preDispatch** functions.
http://zfreak.wordpress.com/2011/04/14/usage-of-init-vs-predispatch-methods-in-zend-front-controller-zend-framework/
If you need 2 separated logics, you can make own function or class in your project and call it or create instance anywhere you need. If your problem is with any render as ACL restrictions... i use own function in controller which retrieve error_access_page and after call $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(). If my users not have access, this show error_page and no render action's phtml file.

hope help =]